# Is there a way to find and remove punctuation from a string in Python?

Tags: python

I have created a function that returns a boolean if a argument contains every letter in the `ascii.lowercase` string (panagram).

within the code, I am using a for loop to find membership of whitespace and punctuation with the `string` module methods `string.whitespace` and `string.punctuation`.

When testing the for loop, the special characters in `string.punctuation` portion seems to not be matching the special characters provide from the for loop.

Please provide the reasoning to `string.punctuation` not working as planned.

```
import string

def ispanagram(text, alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase):
    """Return boolean if argument is contains every letter in the ascii alphabet"""

    alphabet_list = list(alphabet)    
    letter_set = sorted(set(text.lower()))

    for char in letter_set:
        if char in string.whitespace or char in string.punctuation:
            letter_set.remove(char)

    return letter_set == alphabet_list


ispanagram("The quick brown !fox jumps over the lazy dog")
```

Comment: Do you want to return `True` / `False` or a string with punctuations removed?

Comment: Beside the point, but the better method is `all(c in text.lower() for c in alphabet)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is that you're modifying `letter_set` while iterating over it.  This does not work as expected ([explanation](https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/)).

To fix, iterate over a copy:

```
for char in letter_set[:]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this help.

```
import string
import re

def ispanagram(text, alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase):
    """Return boolean if argument is contains every letter in the ascii alphabet"""

    alphabet_list = list(alphabet)

    # just remove all the special characters including space
    text_only_chars = re.sub(r"[-()\"#/@;:<>{}`+=~|.!?, ]", "", text)

    letter_set = sorted(set(text_only_chars.lower()))

    return letter_set == alphabet_list


print(ispanagram("The quick brown !fox jumps over the lazy dog"))

#### Output ####
True
```

Comment: This adds a lot of unneeded complexity.